# NodeJS Express routes in external file 404 Not Found

Tags: node.js, express, nodejs-server

I'm new to NodeJs and express. My goal is to have a separate route file that contains all my application routes. So I created a file called `routes.js`. The content looks like this:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

router.get('auth/register', require('./controllers/auth/register'));

module.exports = router;
```

In my main file, I require the file with this line. The `app` variable contains my express instance.

```
app.use('/', require('./routes'));
```

If I call `http://localhost/auth/register` in my browser, I'm always running into a `404 Not Found` error. When I define the route directly in the main file with `app.get('/auth/register', require('./controllers/auth/register'));` it works well. There are no errors in my console.

Has anyone an idea why my sperate route file does not work? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, I do the following which is to pass the express instance into your routes module:

once I have instantiated my express instance called app

app.js

```
require('./routes.js')(app);
```

routes.js where registerUser us the function to call when the route is matched

```
module.exports = (app) => {
   app.route('/auth/register')
    .post(registerUser);
}
```

Comment: can you share more of the main code where you instantiate express and then register the routes. If you still doing: app.use('/', require('./routes')); then it will not work.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I didn't realize that you use post instead of get. The solution works fine for me.

Comment: Great, I suggest creating separate route files for your various endpoints so you don't have a ton of routes to wade through in a single file.

Answer (score 1):

You want to pass `app` into your routes file. A good pattern for this is to import your routes in your main file, like `const routes = require('./routes');`

In routes, you can define all of your routes like so:

```
module.exports = (app, router) => {
  router.route("/").get()
  router.route("/something_else").post()
  app.use("/api", router)
  ...
};
```

This way, in your main file, you can do: `routes(app, router)` and have access to `app` and `router` inside your `routes.js`.

Comment: How can I get the router in my main file? When I use`app.router` I get this `Error: 'app.router' is deprecated`.

Comment: `let router = express.Router()`